# Как получить вопросы по метке-синониму?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объявил я войну некоторым нерелевантным меткам. Пару штук удалил успешно.
Попался на глаза вопрос с меткой [tsql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql). Эта метка назначена синонимом к метке [sql-server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server). Поэтому на новые вопросы её поставить нельзя, но на нескольких старых вопросах она остаётся. Вот я и хочу удалить (заменить) её с этих вопросов.

На вкладке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags если ввести название этой метки - `tsql` - выдаётся количество вопросов с ней: 16. Но при попытке вывести эти вопросы, автоматически срабатывает синоним и выводятся вопросы с меткой `[sql-server]`. А их много, и перебирать все вручную в поисках нужных будет очень долго.

Как мне получить именно эти 16 вопросов? Чтобы удалить с них лишнюю метку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Готово.

> [image: скриншот]

```
updating post history, 19 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 16 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 5 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'tsql': [tsql] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 3289
tag remapping of [sql-server] and [tsql] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
6 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: Модераторский произвол!